# dump rtl generate memories systemverilog

Tags: ram, dump, verification, system-verilog, generated

I'm new in SystemVerilog and I would like to verify the value inside generate memories.

```
generate
genvar g0, j;
  for( g0 = 0; g0 < NB_CFGDUMP_SLAVE; g0 = g0 + 1)
    begin : g_slave         
      cfgdump_chiplet slave (
        .rst_n        (presetn),
        .clk          (pclk),
        .cfg_id       (8'(g0)), //CONV_STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(g0, 8)),
        .data_in      (data_in),
        .shift        (shift),
        .data_out     (s_data_cfgdump_to_apb[g0]),
        .cfgdump_addr (s_cfgdump_addr[g0]),
        .cfg_data     (s_cfg_data[g0]),
        .cfg_write    (s_cfg_write[g0]),
        .read_data0   (s_read_data[g0][0][33:0]),
        .read_data1   (s_read_data[g0][1][33:0]),
        .read_data2   (s_read_data[g0][2][33:0]),
        .read_data3   (s_read_data[g0][3][33:0]),
        .read_data4   (s_read_data[g0][4][33:0]),
        .read_data5   (s_read_data[g0][5][33:0]),
        .read_data6   (s_read_data[g0][6][33:0]),
        .read_data7   (s_read_data[g0][7][33:0]),
        .read_data8   (s_read_data[g0][8][33:0]),
        .read_data9   (s_read_data[g0][9][33:0]),
        .read_data10  (s_read_data[g0][10][33:0]),
        .read_data11  (s_read_data[g0][11][33:0]),
        .read_data12  (s_read_data[g0][12][33:0]),
        .read_data13  (s_read_data[g0][13][33:0]),
        .read_data14  (s_read_data[g0][14][33:0]),
        .read_data15  (s_read_data[g0][15][33:0]),
        .wr_ready     (16'(1)), // ACK write from register 
        .cfg_sel      (s_cfg_sel[g0])
      );

      for( j = 0; j < nb_target_by_slave; j = j + 1)
        begin : g_ram
          ram ram_i (
            .clk          (pclk),
            .we           (s_cfg_write[g0]),
            .sel          (s_cfg_sel[g0][j]),
            .address      (s_cfgdump_addr[g0]),
            .datain       (s_cfg_data[g0]),
            .dataout      (s_read_data[g0][j][31:0])            
          );

        //end           
        // Redirection du ready sur le bit de poid fort du bus de lecture
        assign s_read_data[g0][j][33] = s_cfg_sel[g0][j];
        // Redirection du code d'erreur sur le bit de poid 32 du bus de lecture
        assign s_read_data[g0][j][32] = 1;
```

I try to dump the values of each RAM without success or find a solution to verify that the read value is the expected. Someone could help me?

Comment: Have you tried the $writememh/$writememb functions? You can call them from inside the memory module with something like `always @(posedge we) begin @(posedge clk); $writememh(mem, $psprintf("ram_dump_%m.hex")); end` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your testcase in GUI mode (cadence) and probe all memory. Than look in to memory viewer. You can easily debug memory data using memory viewer.

You can use -gui command line option to run in GUI mode. Than create probe by going in to design browser and select your memory and right click on it and create probe.